# How were multiple comments posted inside rate limit?

Tags: bug, comments

While reviewing the [not an answer 10k flags](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answernotananswer), I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639947/426671) which has a total of 6 comments posted by the same user in a time span of 5 seconds.  If the [rate-limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) for posting comments is 15 seconds, then how were they able to post 6 identical comments in such a short timespan?

Screenshot since the comments have now been deleted:

> [image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe an answer converted to a comment multiple times. I had that once. I tried to answer, it got converted, I did not get and and tried to comment 3 times.

Comment: Odd; might be a bug via the review system, perhaps?

Comment: @juergend and anyone else curious; the comments in question were all: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn I looked at the users review history and I didn't see this item, maybe I missed it.

Comment: Hmm... good point...

Comment: @juergend But it's a comment on an answer, not a question.

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn I blame the hats, too many people are flagging stuff for the hats!  :)

Comment: It is rare, but I occasionally see a comment that I post get stalled from my browser to the server.  Comment postings get queued on the server if the server is busy, so if I refresh the page and try again, I might find the same comment posted two or three times in succession, once the server gets un-busy.  This might not happen for a half-minute or so, so the poster might have left before he noticed the comment duplication.

Comment: @TheGrinch I've seen maybe 1-2 duplicated comments, but 6 times seemed very strange thus the reason for my question.  :)

Comment: I think my record is four.  In any case, it's rare enough where it's probably not a major issue.