# Raise an auto-flag on duplicate comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags

I am using [What flags are automatically raised by the system?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317987/2415822) from Meta.SO for reference (I could not find a Meta.SE equivalent post).

I believe an auto-flag should be raised when duplicate comments are posted.  I mean, how constructive can something like this be?

[image: Duplicate Comments]

Comment: This looks like a bug - if two of the same comment get posted, the latter one should be discarded as an accidental duplicate. Now, posting the same comment to multiple posts is perfectly fine, and there are scripts to help with that.

Comment: What were those 6 users thinking when they upvoted the last comment?

Comment: Moderators have a tool that gives them a list of users posting duplicate comments. I'm not sure an auto-flag is needed.

Comment: @bluefeet can you diff that with the list of users who use the canned comment userscript, please?

Comment: @bluefeet I was not, but I figured an additional step could be taken in preventing duplicate comments like this.  Do you feel that the current dupe comment tool is sufficient?  Aaaaaand you edited your comment.

Comment: This was asked for a while ago and we didn't go with a flag because of the concerns @JanDvorak raises with users using canned comment scripts. It was going to be too noisy, so we decided to make it a list that moderators can review as needed and clean-up, contact users (if needed), etc.

Comment: I do not think the dupe closure is correct here.  This request is to catch a user posting multiple comments to the same post which should be fairly trivial to find and not have false positives unlike the request that this is liked to.

Comment: The bug for multiple comments being posted [has also been reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212174/how-were-multiple-comments-posted-inside-rate-limit).  I still don't find an auto-flag is really necessary because this is such an edge case, but feel free to vote to reopen @NathanOliver

Comment: @bluefeet I would love to but Meta.SE does not allow me to use my SO rep.

Comment: @rene They really felt it gave the message emphasis

Comment: @JanDvorak - Per what bluefeet said, I've found it easy to scan down the list to see only the comments that clearly weren't part of a canned comment userscript (or were part of a bad script). I just have to remind myself to use the tool from time to time to catch these. It's easy to pick out and ignore people performing moderation tasks.

Comment: @BradLarson do you feel that an auto-comment would help more than the tool currently does?  I am not trying to create redundant tools for mods, I am just trying to figure out what would work the best.

Comment: @JAL - I think the tool is serving the intended purpose. We can easily identify and clear out spammed comments or other repeated noise, without having to wade through a bunch of flags. A new auto-flag for users with a recent history of flagged rude comments takes this on from another angle, and has been an aid in identifying problematic commenters. That's currently in testing on SO and elsewhere, and is being refined based on our feedback.